# How to set parent width around dynamic elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to set the width of a parent div so that all of its child divs display on one line (horizontally). I'm looping through the children and using jQuery's `outerWidth(true)` function to find the total necessary width. But although the calculation seems to be correct to me, the inner elements break onto two lines. I'm testing in Chrome, FF and Safari, and IE9. What am I missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <style>
        #outer{
            width: 100px;
            height: 200px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        .inner{
            display: inline-block;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            margin-right: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            background-color: yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="outer">
        <div class="inner">0</div>
        <div class="inner">1</div>
        <div class="inner">2</div>
        <div class="inner">3</div>
        <div class="inner">4</div>
        <div class="inner">5</div>
        <div class="inner">6</div>
        <div class="inner">7</div>
        <div class="inner">8</div>
        <div class="inner">9</div>
    </div>

    <script src="../js/jquery.1.11.0.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var itemsWidthWithMargin = 0;
        $(".inner").each(function() {
            itemsWidthWithMargin += $(this).outerWidth(true);
        });
        $("#outer").width(itemsWidthWithMargin);
        alert(itemsWidthWithMargin);
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of inline-block, use float:left;

```
.inner{
            float:left;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            margin-right: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            box-sizing:border-box;
            background-color: yellow;
        }
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qG3Fm/)

With inline-block you have this extra white space: [Screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/NMWO5rHmPnb).

But nice and tight with float: left [Screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/eoY1ezcNkGV).

You can read more about that extra space [here](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).